# Prove $\forall x\,∀y (x^2 < y+1)$ is false

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The domain of discourse $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

Q: $\forall x\,\forall y (x^2 < y+1)$

Answer given by book: False by counterexample, $x=3, y=0$

The book says "to prove $∀x\,∀y P(x,y)$ is false, where the discourse $X \times Y$, find one value of $x$ subset of $X$ and one value for $y$ subset of $Y$ to make $P(x, y)$ false"

**But why? I cannot seem to understand the logics behind the answer nor the explanation.**

The way I think about the problem for every real number $x$ and every real number $y$ such that when $1$ added to $y$ is greater than $x^2$.

Therefore, I conclude that the statement will always be true. The answer above is wrong since $y$ can be $9$, so $9 < 9+1$ is true...

Thank you

Comment: Your Q. is false by the counter example given since $\;x^2=3^2=9\rlap{\;\;/}<1=0+1=1+y\;$ .

Comment: The propositions says if the stament $x^2 < y+1$ is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Once you find at least one $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and one $y \in \mathbb{R}$ that don't satisfy it, then it can't be true, cause it can't be true for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Antioquia3943 To write $\;\Bbb R\;$ do write \Bbb R between dollars .

Comment: Sometimes true doesn't meant always true.  "Prove everybody loves boiled spinach and eggplant.  Proof:  My grandmother made it once and my grandfather said "Wow, this is really good.  I love it".  Therefore my grandfather loves it so this is true".  No go.  Jane done the street hates it.  So it is false.  $9 < 9 + 1$ is true.  So it is **SOMETIMES** true.  $500billion^2 < 1+1$ is false.  So it is not always true.  To the statement "It is always true".... is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your problem: you say (correctly)

> for ... every real number y

Then you say

> since y can be 9

Yes, y *can be* 9, but you need an argument that's true for *every* y.

Comment: Oh, that's silly on my part. I see it now, thank you.

Comment: I visualized it wrong, thought of ∀x∀y as two circles that represent \Bbb R where each x of X can map to each y of Y, but not all.

Answer (score 1):

$$∀x∀y (x^2 < y+1)$$

This is a claim, essentially, that every(any) $x$ and every(any) $y$ is such that $x^2 \lt (y+1).$

While you may find values of $x, y$ that satisfy the given inequality, those are only *some* values for $x, y$.

Counter example (given): $x = 3, y=0$: and $x^2 = 3^2 = 9, \quad 0+1= 1$.

Clearly, we have a counterexample, because if $x=3$ and $y = 0$, Then $9\not\lt 1$.

Note that to prove $\lnot \forall x \forall y(x^2\lt y+1),$ all that is required is to provide one counter example to demonstrates the negation.

That is, the negation of "for all" is **not** "for none."  The negation of a claim about *all x...$, is that "not all x...", i.e. showing one or more counterexamples to the claim.

That is, $$\exists x\exists y(x^2 \geq  y+1).$$

Comment: This is another way to look at the problem (which I did not know), so thank you!